# Space Hulk: Death Angel - playing a 'multi-player' game solo

Tags: death-angel

I just beat the game solo but could not do so when I had a teammate. I get the feeling beating it is easier when you are solo b/c the most genestealers that can pop out is 2. And having smaller swarms is greatly beneficial to rolling for defense.

Anyways, I was wondering if anyone has tried playing a solo mission but with more than 6 space marines. Do you think it is easier or harder?

Answer (score 1):

I find it harder with more players. Mostly because people tend to coordinate less... and so suboptimal decisions are more common.

There also is the issue of more genestealers per event card, but more troops means more shots made.

Worst blowouts I've seen have been 6p games.

I've run the game with a 3p setup for 2p, with one of the two controlling two groups, and it works fine that way. (P3 dropped out after turn 1.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "too many cooks" problem.  If you've ever played Vlaada Chvatil's very entertaining boardgame Space Alert, you'll know that a rather complicated logistical problem can become next to impossible given multiple player agents and only limited time to co-ordinate...